# sqlalchemy How to treat each row in database as a single list and iterate through each list?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to build a simple multi choice quiz platform using sqlalchemy, flask and python3. I have a index.html page, part of it looks like:

```
{% for q in quiz %}
    <li>{{ q.question }}</li>
    <input type='radio' value='A' name='choice' /> {{q.optionA}}
    <input type='radio' value='B' name='choice' /> {{q.optionB}}
    <input type='radio' value='C' name='choice' /> {{q.optionC}}
    <input type='radio' value='D' name='choice' /> {{q.optionD}}
{% endfor %}
```

and in my routes.py, I added a line below so that I can iterate through my quiz database as a list:

```
 quiz = Quiz.query.all()
 return render_template('index.html', title='Home', posts=posts, quiz=quiz)
```

and in my database the Quiz looks like:

```
class Quiz(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question = db.Column(db.String(150))
    optionA = db.Column(db.String(150))
    optionB = db.Column(db.String(150))
    optionC = db.Column(db.String(150))
    optionD = db.Column(db.String(150))
    answer = db.Column(db.String(1))
    quizCode = db.Column(db.String(2))
```

So far I only have two questions in my database and they look like:

- 2+2   
  4. 5. 6. 7.
- 2+3   
  2. 3. 4. 5.

Then I have problem because every time I run it, and try to select an option on the index.html, I can only select one, when I move to next question and make a select, the options in above question will deselect itself. And I know it's because all options are in the same group name='choice', however I don't know how to solve this.

I was trying to iterate through each row as a list so that I can make each question as a single group:

```
o = Quiz.query.filter_by(quizCode="1").first()   #I was trying to test if this works
oneItem = o.query.all()    #I want to treat o as a single list so that I can only iterate through o
```

but I failed. So any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have indeed correctly pointed out the issue, the value gets deselected as the group name is not unique.

One way to solve this is by using the id of your quiz in the checkbox name.

```
{% for q in quiz %}
   <li>{{ q.question }}</li>
   <input type='radio' value='A' name='choice_{{ q.id }}' /> {{q.optionA}}
   <input type='radio' value='B' name='choice_{{ q.id }}' /> {{q.optionB}}
   <input type='radio' value='C' name='choice_{{ q.id }}' /> {{q.optionC}}
   <input type='radio' value='D' name='choice_{{ q.id }}' /> {{q.optionD}}
{% endfor %}
```

Notice how the checkbox name is now `choice_{{ q.id }}`, which will make sure it stays unique inside the loop.

While the above solution should resolve your issue I'd highly recommend using something like [flask-wtf](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#creating-forms) to construct your forms.